# Proving maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contain a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I want to show that $M$ must contain some prime number $p$.

**My attempt**

Assume not. We know $M$ can't contain $1$. Let $q$ be the smallest positive integer in $M$. Then $q$ must be composite, say $p|q$ for some prime $p$. Define $M_p:=${$α+pβ : \alpha\in M$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$}. It is easy to see that $M_p$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Now, if I can show that $1\notin M_p,$ this should imply a contradiction. But how can I show that $1\notin M_p$? I am struggling with this.

Comment: You are assuming that $M$ contains some positive integer; I don't think that is obvious.

Comment: I already proved that $M$ contains a nonzero integer, although I have not stated this above. And if it contains a nonzero integer, then it must contain a positive integer.

Comment: Once you have a nonzero integer $m$ in $M$, then since $M$ is a prime ideal, then one of its prime factors is in $M$. Proving that $M$ contains a nonzero integer is the hard part of the proof.

Comment: Thank you, I have now proven what I wanted to show.

Comment: Have you tried this with a specific ring, like $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-163}]$ or $\mathbb Z[\root 3 \of 2]$? It might point the way to a generalization.

Comment: I'm curious how to show $M$ contains a nonzero integer. Can you give me a hint?